# move_uploadfile() problema

Tags: php

Buenas tengo un problema en la subida de un archivo a mi servidor Web. Creía que tenía que ver con los permisos pero me he asegurado que el owner _www pueda escribir y leer en los directorios que quiero manipular.

Adjunto el código par ver si podéis ver el error:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['nombre'])){
  header("Location: ./login.php");

}else{
$id = $_SESSION['nombre'];
$target_dir ="./UsuarioRegistrados/".$id."/perfil/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["pic"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["pic"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["pic"]["size"] > 500000000000000000000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            rename($target_file, $target_dir."fondoUsuario.jpeg");
            header("Location: ./usuarioConfig.php".$url);
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}

 ?>
```

El problema está en el último if del código. El error que me devuelve el servidor es el siguiente:

> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(/WEB/UsuarioRegistrados/*****/perfil/1366_2000.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/WEB/cambiarFotoPerfil.php on line 44

Comment: Haz un `echo $target_file;` , verifica qué ruta imprime y verifica que los directorios de esa ruta existen. El mensaje dice que no encontró el archivo o el directorio. Haz también un `var_dump($_FILES);` para verificar si el archivo se está enviando bien al servidor.

Comment: Parece ser que  todo está como debe

Comment: ¿Cómo que *parece ser*? Debes estar seguro. ¿Qué imprime como ruta y qué imprime el `var_dump`? ¿Puedes mostrarnos?

Comment: Con parece ser me refiero a que todo está como debe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esto te puede ayudar:
agrege algunas correcciones y mejoras a tu codigo!

```
<?php 

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['nombre'])){
  header("Location: ./login.php");

}else{

$id = $_SESSION['nombre'];
$ROOT = dirname(__FILE__);   // path actual
$DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;   // directory separator agreaga / o \ dependiendo del sistema operativo

$imagenAllowed = ["png","jpeg","jpg","gif"]; // imagenes aceptadas
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["pic"]["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$target_dir = $ROOT.$DS."UsuarioRegistrados".$DS.$id.$DS."perfil".$DS;
$target_file = $target_dir . $_FILES["pic"]["name"];

// esto es para evitar que 2 imagenes se llamen igual
//$target_file = $target_dir . str_replace (".","",microtime(true)). $imageFileType; 

if (!file_exists($target_dir)) {           // valida que existe la carpeta
    if(!mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true)){   // valida que se cree
      die("no se puede crear la carpeta");       // termina la ejecucion si no se puede crear la ruta!
    } 
}

$uploadOk = 1;

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["pic"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["pic"]["size"] > 500000000000000000000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Allow certain file formats
    if(!in_array($imageFileType,$imagenAllowed)) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk != 0) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            rename($target_file, $target_dir."fondoUsuario.jpeg");
            header("Location: ./usuarioConfig.php".$url);
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado. Muchas gracias!